# How To Get Text Wrapped Around In A Note Box In Cisco Packet Tracer?

Tags: packet-tracer, interface, documentation

I am new to Packet Tracer, and I am trying to refresh my CCNA knowledge. I downloaded and installed PT version 8.2.1 which is the latest version by today (04/23/2023). I have been using it for a while now. However, I am facing a weird problem that I have not found a solution to on the Internet or anywhere else.

When I add a note and type inside the note box, all the text appears as one line except where "Enter" is used. I tried to find a way to resize the box or change its properties with no luck.

**So, how can I get the text wrapped automatically inside PT Notes?**

As you know they are extremely helpful in explanation and documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually adding "Enter" is the only way I have found. Wish someone had a better answer.